# please help me! I do not know what i am doing wrong

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is my code

```
const LinkComponent = () => {
  const linksArray = [
    { url: '/transactions', lable: 'Transactions' },
    { url: '/inventory-orders', lable: 'Inventory Order' },
  ];
  const listLinks = linksArray.map();

  return (
    <NavItem>
      <NavLink>
        <Link to={listLinks.url} exact activeStyle={{ color: 'purple' }}>
          {listLinks.lable}
        </Link>
      </NavLink>
    </NavItem>
  );
};
```

and i get TypeError: undefined is not a function
I ha no idea why

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review the guidelines on [ask] to improve the odds of getting an answer that helps you.  Good luck!

Comment: Maybe you should pass predicate to map method? Or if you want to make a shallow copy use ```[...linksArray]``` or ```linksArray.slice()```.

Comment: You should map over to `linksArray` and create new `Link` component to each element of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const LinkComponent = () => {
  const linksArray = [
    { url: "/transactions", lable: "Transactions" },
    { url: "/inventory-orders", lable: "Inventory Order" }
  ];
  const listLinks = linksArray.map();

  return (
    <NavItem>
      {listLinks.map(link => (
        <NavLink>
          <Link to={link.url} exact activeStyle={{ color: "purple" }}>
            {link.lable}
          </Link>
        </NavLink>

      )})}
    </NavItem>
  );
};
```

Try this. `listLinks` is an array. So you cannot do `listLinks.lable`. You can only do that on its children object.